# How to handle invalid state after move especially for objects with validating constructor?

Tags: c++

I made a class for a function's argument to delegate its validation and also for function overloading purposes.

Throwing from constructor guarantees that the object will either be constructed in a valid state or will not be constructed at all. Hence, there is no need to introduce any checking member functions like `explicit operator bool() const`.

```
// just for exposition
const auto &certString = open_cert();
add_certificate(cert_pem{certString.cbegin(), certString.cend()}); // this will either throw 
                                                                    // or add a valid certificate.
                                                                    // cert_pem is a temporary
```

However, there are issues which I don't see a appealing solution for:
Argument-validation class might itself be made non-persistent - to be used only for validation as a temporary object. But what about classes that are allowed to be persistent? That is living after function invocation:

```
// just for exposition
const auto &certString = open_cert();

cert_pem cert{certString.cbegin(), certString.cend()}; // allowed to throw
cert_pem moved = std::move(cert); // cert invalidated
cert_pem cert_invalid = std::move(cert); // is not allowed to throw

add_certificate(cert_invalid); // we lost the whole purpoce
```

I can see several ways to treat this without introducing state-checking (thus declaring a class stateful) functions:

1. **Declare object "unusable" after move.** - A really simple recipe for disaster
2. **Declare move constructor and assignment operator deleted. Allow only copy** - Resources might be very expensive to copy. Or even not possible if using a PIMPL idiom.
3. **Use heap allocation when need an object to be persistent** - this looks like most obvious. But has an unnecessary penalty on performance. Especially when some class has as members several such objects - there will be several memory allocations upon construction.

Here is a code example for *2)*:

```
/**
     * Class that contains PEM certificate byte array.
     * To be used as an argument. Ensures that input certificate is valid, otherwise throws on construction.
     */
    class cert_pem final
    {
    public:

        template <typename IterT>
        cert_pem(IterT begin, IterT end)
            : value_(begin, end)
        {
            validate(value_);
        }

        const std::vector<uint8_t>& Value() const noexcept(false)
        {
            return value_;
        }

        cert_pem (const cert_pem &) = default;
        cert_pem & operator=(const cert_pem &) = default;

        cert_pem (cert_pem &&) = delete;
        cert_pem & operator=(cert_pem &&) = delete;

    private:
        /**
         * \throws std::invalid_argument
         */
        static void Validate(const std::vector<uint8_t>& value) noexcept(false);
        static void ValidateNotEmpty(const std::vector<uint8_t>& value) noexcept(false);

    private:
        std::vector<uint8_t> value_;
    };
```

**Is there another way to handle this problem without these shortcomings? Or will I have to choose one of the above?**

---

I think that with argument-validating classes a good way would be to not allow it to be persistent - only temporary object is allowed. But I am not sure if it is possible in C++.

Comment: If you are doing crypto, asymmetric crypto even, I don't expect a single shared_ptr to make an even remotely measurable difference. So you could implement your pimpl with shared_ptr and get, I believe, everything you seem to want for almost free.

Comment: @bitmask certificate validating class is just an example that is handy at the moment. This is a recurring problem that I wanted to address a long time ago. The question is not about crypto

Comment: To keep people from using moved object, I think looking for static analyzer might be another way. Or something like clang-tidy's [bugprone-use-after-move](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58163193/4123703) switch.

Comment: I see. Well, if you have an object, generally, that has an invariant saying "I'm always in a usable state if constructed" moving it (*actually* moving it) cannot work with that invariant. In that case you probably should go with 2 and make good use of copy elision.

Comment: Or using an unamed scope`{}` to limit `cert`'s lifetime.

Comment: @LouisGo that is the problem. moved object is commonly considered to be in an intermedate state, though still usable

Comment: And that is why `std::move` is code smell. It's left to the user to not use a moved object. It's too bad the compiler isn't allowed to implicitly move objects when they are not used again. That would cover all the safe cases of `std::move`.

Comment: Maybe deleting both copy and move constructors and assignment operators would work well. If you need to be able to copy the object, providing a `copy()` member function could be useful, and that way you need to explicitly do the expensive operation rather than having implicit copies everywhere.

Comment: Asking ten C++ developers for a "commonly-accepted way to do <X>" guarantees at least eleven different answers. This is mostly a matter of opinion. For example, I don't see anything wrong with option 1, which is just another way of saying that "cert_pem" may represent an entity without an installed certificate. It's logically equivalent to an uninitialized pointer. There are plenty of them. And they're perfectly fine, as long as you don't use them. Except in the object's case you can avoid undefined behavior by having all methods check if the cert_pem is empty, and throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to maintain two invariants at once, and their semantics are in conflict. The first invariant is the validity of the certificate. The second is for memory management.

For the first invariant, you decided that there can be no invalid constructed object, but for the second, you decided that the object can be either valid or unspecified<sup>†</sup>. This is only possible because the deallocation has a check somewhere.

There is no way around this: you either add a check for the first or you decouple the invariants. One way of decoupling them is to follow the design of `std::lock_guard`

```
cert c = open_cert(); // c is guaranteed to not have memory leaks and is movable
{
    cert_guard cg{c};  // cg is guaranteed to be valid, but cg is non-movable
}
```

But wait, you might ask, how do you transfer the validity to another `cert_guard`?

Well, you can't.

That is the semantics you chose for the first invariant: it is valid exactly during the lifetime of the object. That is the *entire point*.

<sub>† Unspecified and invalid as far as the certificate is concerned.</sub>

Comment: "decoupling the innvariants" seems like "separation of concerns". Maybe Argument-validating class must do only that - validate and not be stored as a persistent member.

Answer (score 1):

The question aims to design a type such that:

1. an object of the type always satisfies a given invariant
2. an object of the type is "usable" as a non-temporary

The question then makes a *leap* from (2) to ask that the type be movable. But it need not be: copy and move operations could be defined as deleted. The question fails to motivate why the move operations are necessary. If that is a need, it comes from an unstated requirement. A non-movable class can be emplaced in a map, returned from a function, and used in many other ways. It admittedly can be more painful to use, but it can be used.

So that's one option that's not listed: define copy and move operations as deleted.

Otherwise, let's assume we do want:

1. an object of the type always satisfies a given invariant
2. the type is movable

This is *not* in conflict. Every copyable class is movable, and copying is a valid strategy here. Remember that move operations allow a "potentially smarter" copy, by allowing the source to be mutated. There are still two C++ objects, and it is still a logical copy, but with an assumption that the source won't be needed anymore in its current state (so you can steal from it!). There is no difference in the C++ interface, only in the totally unchecked documented behavior of the type after a move operation.

Defining move operations as deleted gives you a copyable class. This is your second option listed. Assigning from an xvalue (`cert_pem moved = std::move(cert)`) will still compile, but will not invalidate the source. It will still be considered movable by the language. The trade-off is as you note, copies can be expensive. Note that PIMPL authors can give their types copy operations, that's a choice they make about what the interface of the type should be, and the idiom doesn't prevent it.

The third choice is a version of the second. By putting values behind a `shared_ptr`, one can make an expensive-to-copy type cheap to copy. But we still rely on copy as the strategy for move.

The first choice amounts to weakening the invariant in (1). A moved-from object satisfying a different set of invariants than a normal object is very typical in C++. It is annoying, but in many cases it is the best we can do. When only one object can exist satisfying the invariant (think: non-null `unique_ptr`) the moved-from object *must* violate it.

The accepted answer amounts to my first option combined with delayed construction: define copy and move operations as deleted. Creating the guard can throw if the object was moved-from. The guard is just the type maintaining the invariant, and it is non-movable. We can delay its construction because such types are difficult to manage. We do that by keeping an object that knows enough about how to construct it. This strategy exists in other forms (`emplace` functions and `piecewise_construct` constructors to construct objects in their eventual place, factory functions to construct the object at will, etc.).

However, the description in the accepted answer leaves a bit to be desired, in my opinion. The desire is to maintain the invariant while being movable (this is assumed). Being movable doesn't require that the moved-from object satisfy an invariant or be unspecified. That's a choice the author of the type makes, and what choices are available is exactly the question, by my reading of it. Although the example given only implicated memory, and the first answer mentioned memory, my reading of the question was more general: maintaining invariants in movable classes.

Knowing that all copyable classes are movable, that move is a "smart" copy, and that there are two objects in and after a move operation will help in understanding why there's such limited options here. One has to leave that source object in some state.

My advice is to embrace the radioactive moved-from object. That's the approach in the standard library, and defaulted move operations will obey that more often than not. For such types, there must be some "empty" state for moved-from objects, so all types are effectively optional and a default constructor can also be defined to get an object in that empty state.

Comment: an "obvious" case for "movable" argument-validating class would be a "necessity" to store its objects in an array of some kind (`std::vector`). But Passer By in his answer has a good point for decoupling validation and resources.

Comment: I was also thinking of having a `shared_ptr` for resources within. But I think that forsing an allocation upon user is not as good as leaving up to him whether he wants to wrap the object with `shared_ptr` or not.

Comment: Addressing your conclusion: that is the core problem for me - redunduncy. If you have a validation method (like `std::unique_ptr`), validating constructor is redundant - you will still have to do the checks after construction. For argument-validating classes there is no sence in having a validating member function. If only there was a way to force non-persistency for objects...

Comment: Re the storage in an array: that would indeed need movable. As you probably realize, alternative container choices could be usable with a non-movable type (std::list, say). So, yes, that's a trade-off to consider.

Comment: For storing in containers I think a good solution would indeed be decoupling the resources. Containers would store the resources (which are movable), not the argument-validating class instances.

Comment: **Except...** that I don't think it holds up to scrutiny. If you took that answer on its face, you'd have two types `cert` which contains a vector and is movable, and `cert_guard` that is non-movable and guarantees the contents are a valid cert. But, `cert` is movable, so there is a moved-from state which the programmer promises not to rely on its state.

Comment: In other words, this relies on a programmer *promise* that `cert` is not moved-from when the guard is created. But if a programmer *promise* is good enough for you, you can just make `cert_guard` movable and ask the programmer not to rely on it in a moved-from state.
All one has done is relocate the question to `cert`. The decoupling is false. You're still in the strategy where moved-from == radioactive.

Comment: I generalized the strategy in my answer to say "deferred construction". If instead of actually having the vector, `cert` knew how to make or find one... you could imagine situations where that is cheap and you could keep `cert` copyable without the downside. But if you want `cert` to already have a vector, you've just relocated the problem.
This is also why I was motivated to write the answer. I found PasserBy's argument compelling at first. It definitely provided food for thought. But I pondered it for a while, and couldn't find a way to make the explanation work.

Comment: On the conclusion, yes, it's annoying. Invariants and non-copy moves interact poorly. This is true regardless of if its memory, a different type of unique resource (e.g. open file), or some other invariant (valid cert, int in a range). The only real way

Comment: that the unique resources come into play is that copying is no longer a strategy... Otherwise, the considerations, trade-offs, and strategies are all very similar. When we have a destructive move (aka relocation), or when Rust is an option (which has destructive move), this problem will be solved. But for now, you'll be fighting against the language if you want moved-from objects to have meaningful state.